# Make only one of many controls visible based on value of another control

Tags: wpf

I have a ComboBox bound to a collection of objects defined as this.

```
public class TierOption
{
    public string Option { get; set; }
    public Type DataType { get; set; }
}
public class TierOptions : ObservableCollection<Tier1Option>
{

}
```

I have 3 other controls related to this ComboBox, which are a TextBox, ComboBox, or a WPFToolKit:DatePicker.

I need to show only the related control which corresponds to the datatype(Type) of the object selected in the first ComboBox and neither of the others.

Pseudo Code Example:
    (Probably too close to butchered C# but hopefully it conveys the idea)

```
switch (ComboBox.SelectedItem.DataType)
{
     case String:
          TextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          ComboBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          DatePicker.Visibility = Visibility. Hidden;
     break;
     case DateTime:
          TextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          ComboBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          DatePicker.Visibility = Visibility. Visible;
     break;
     <...so forth and so on...>
}
```

My attempts have resulted in very non-wpf looking convoluted messes which don't work regardless.  Being new to wpf I'm trying very hard to stay true to the best design practices.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can play with DataTemplate with DataType property

```
<...Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DateTime}">
        <DatePicker .../>
    </DataTemplate>
    ...
</...Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myComboBox}"/>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"/>
```

The code above is just the idea, you could have to make adjustements. For example you won't be able to modify a string item itself (you could have to encapsulate each item of your list)

If your list contains all items of the same type, you can use a ContentTemplateSelector on contentControl.

```
 ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=YourCombBox}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource YourTemplateSelector}"
```

[MSDN DOC about ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx)

Comment: +1 I think this idea is better than my initial idea of using triggers. If your amount of controls grows, triggers would make it more difficult. Having different datatemplates is the way to go imho because it is easy to add more controls later on if necessary.

Comment: This looks to me like it would work if each object in the first ComboBox was of a specific Type but every object is of the same Type (TierOption) which has a property defining DataType.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @elo Sorry you're right! I read too fast, so you have to make a class  (that inherits from TierOption) for each type of option you put in your list.

Comment: @elo I added you a solution using a TemplateSelector. You probably don't have many other choices. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Jonas Brilliant, that's it exactly!  TemplateSelector was the route I went.  Now I've just got to figure out how to dynamically populate the templated ComboBox but I'll do my homework on that before asking more questions.  Given that this is my first question on StackOverflow, what's the proper etiquette aside from marking your response as the solution?  Should I edit my original post with code samples of my final solution or what?  Thanks!

Comment: @elo You just have to put a tick on my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the detail visibility to ElementName=ComboBox Path=SelectedItem.DataType. And you will need to use a converter that returns visibility.   You will need two converters return opposite answers.  If you have more than 2 combination then some more in the line of Jonas.

I assumed Type was a system class and it appears to be a custom class.  Extend that class to have additional properties.  Even if Type was a system type you could just create a class that implements it and extend it.

```
   public Visibility TextBoxVisibility { get; }
   public Visibility ComboBoxVisibility { get; }
   ...
```

Then on `TextBox` bind the visibility

```
   Visisbility="{binding ElementName=Combobox Path=SelectedItem.DataType.TextBoxVisibility]";
```